# PHP спарсить значения из кода по url

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить отдельные значения по ссылке www.wowhead.com/achievement=12103&power. 
Текст, который там отображается

```
$WowheadPower.registerAchievement(12103, 0, {
    name_enus: '...And Chew Mana Buns',
    icon: 'ability_demonhunter_chaosstrike',
    tooltip_enus: '<table><tr><td><b class="q">...And Chew Mana Buns</b> <span class="q0">10 Points </span></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><br />Slay 2000 non-trivial demons in Krokuun, Mac\'Aree, and the Antoran Wastes.</td></tr></table>',
    tooltip2_enus: ''
});
```

Подскажите, как получить значения item и tooltip_enu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете эмулировать работу этого api, используя любой интерпретатор javascript и eval(с учётом ограничений CORS, нужно делать это либо не в браузере, либо в том же домене):

```
{
 let $WowheadPower = {
   data: {},
   registerAchievement: function(id, _, data) {
     this.data[id] = data;
   }
 };

 fetch('http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=12103&power')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(js => eval(js))
  .then(() => console.log($WowheadPower.data))
}
```

Для php Вы можете посмотреть на расширение [v8js](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php)

---

Если пользоваться этими чанками - не принципиально - воспользуйтесь [BattleNet API](https://dev.battle.net/io-docs)

Comment: нашла такой вариант https://us.api.battle.net/wow/achievement/6?locale=en_US&apikey=rzsszn6r9m6b75g4tg8bxx6ep7yhp9uc, только  у меня несколько id и грузит несколько секунд (

Comment: Загружайте их параллельно - и кешируйте, эти данные почти никогда не меняются

Comment: не понимаю, как параллельно?

Comment: Например, через [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php)